# Get next / previous record from MySQL query ordered by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm running a query through my MySQL database (MariaDB 10.3) which goes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY priority DESC, expiration_date ASC, id ASC
```

A sample of this table with given ordering would look like this:

| id | ... | priority | expiration_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ... | 2 | 2022-07-01 12:00:00 |
| 7 | ... | 2 | 2022-07-03 12:00:00 |
| 6 | ... | 2 | 2022-07-04 12:00:00 |
| 9 | ... | 1 | 2022-07-02 12:00:00 |
| 4 | ... | 1 | 2022-07-05 12:00:00 |
| 11 | ... | 1 | 2022-07-05 12:00:00 |

Now I already have the ID of a specific record and I'm trying to retrieve the record which would precede / succeed said record in the query result by the given ordering through SQL as well. Say I have the record ID `6`, and I want to have the records with ID `9` and `7` respectively returned.

With an ordering by a single, unique column this would be quite easy to get in a single query, but I'm not sure how to handle multiple non-unique columns. Can someone tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question to explain exactly what output you want here.

Comment: What version of MySQL? The version of MySQL that you use is vital information, MySQL before version 8 lacks features that are likely to solve this problem simply e.g. `lag()` or `lead()`

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea the LAG and LEAD features are available for MySQL as well, I always thought they were Oracle exclusive. Thanks for the hint, this might actually solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following Paul Maxwell's hint about `LEAD` and `LAG`, I was able to compose a working query like this:

```
SELECT t.next_id 
FROM (
    SELECT id, 
        LEAD(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY priority DESC, expiration_date ASC, id ASC) AS next_id 
    FROM my_table
) t 
WHERE t.id = ?
```

Retrieving the previous record works accordingly with `LAG`.